# Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'Bom' available as request attribute

Tags: spring-mvc, hibernate-mapping

My code is as follows:

```
@RequestMapping("/ViewItemBom.htm")
        public ModelAndView viewItemBom(@RequestParam(value = "selectedId", required = false) String itemSeq)
                throws Exception {
            itemBom = bomService.getItemBom(itemSeq);
    // long sponsorSeq = BaseWebAppHelper.getSponsorSeqAsLong(session);
    //
    // itemBom.setSponsorSeq(sponsorSeq);
    //
    // // bom.setBranchSeqForm(branchSeq);

    return new ModelAndView("bom/BomAdd", "Bom", itemBom);
}
```

Comment: Please share more info about code

Comment: Please say where i did wrong in my code

Comment: You just mentioned u r code. but elaborate more about your problem.

Comment: When i am click on the view button its just showing as blank page

Answer (score 0):

That error mean that your view doesn't have a variable called 'Bom'that you are passing in `new ModelAndView("bom/BomAdd", "Bom", itemBom);`

try to add before `return` :

```
ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("bom/BomAdd");
model.addAttribute("Bom", itemBom);
```